# Business concerns vs persistence concerns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, persistence, domain-driven-design

I am using Entity Framework to handle persistence between my core model and the database. I cannot see a way of satisfactorily working with EF without compromising my domain entities just to enable persistence. I really want to implement a rich domain model which is truly ignorant of how it's state gets stored.

For example, the EF convention is to map multiple relationships to virtual ICollections. I realise that I could make the member protected, but this won't work if the core model and the EntityTypeConfigurations are in different assemblies.

I would rather protect my model from getting into an invalid state by protecting it's associated members, preferring the following...

```
public class MyEntity {

    private ICollection<Thing> myThings { get; set; }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<Thing> MyThings { get { return myThings.AsReadOnly(); } }

    public void AddThing(Thing toAdd) { // validate, etc }

}
```

Possible solutions I have identified (none of them I am really happy with)...

1. Map to DTOs, and have the domain entity wrap it's attendant DTO, so the DTO has the data, and the entity has the behaviour.
2. Move EntityTypeConfigurations into the Core assembly.
3. Make the Core and Infrastructure.Data.Ef projects "friends" and use the internal access modifier (I really hate this idea).
4. Accept the limitation. Leave the collections to be publically mutated and perform some other validation before they are persisted.
5. Forget EF and go back to ADO,NET.

Are there any other ideas? Is Persistence Ignorance an unattainable goal?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a Repository pattern?

Comment: Your Domain Entities could be your EF entities without the need of referencing EF in your Core layer or dealing with internal access modifiers, have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945104/onion-architecture-entity-framework-code-first-models-dataannotations/16961124#16961124)

Answer (score 0):

My prefered solution, after trying to beat EF into submission and failing, is:

1. Create your domain entities, fully persistence ignorant.
2. In your repositories, use EF entities internally, but map these to/from your domain entities.  Your repository should only accept and return domain entities.
3. Use auto-generation from DB, instead of Code First, unless maintaining 2 sets of entities provides any great benefit.  Usually I find it's not worth it.

This will of course, as I put it, cut the ORM off at the knees.  You won't get lazy loading, but lazy loading often doesn't often work well in DDD, as you've have to be exposing your database design all the way up through your app.

Your ORM (EF) will be completely hidden from your app, only the repositories in your data layer will have internal dealings with it.

Answer (score 0):

My advice: move away from Fluent Mapping, use XML. With .edmx file you can easily* map even private properties.

- except it's quite verbose syntax.